# Square of primary ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

Is there any example of  a $P$-primary ideal $I$ in a noetherian domain $R$ such that $I^2=PI \not=P^2$?

Comment: The question seems clear enough now. $I$ is a primary ideal, and $P$, the radical of $I$, is the associated prime ideal. Meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1207/2926

Comment: Solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850130/an-example-of-an-m-primary-ideal-in-noetherian-local-domain

Answer (score 7):

What a fun problem for the holiday season! Yes,  an example is $R=\mathbb C[a,b,c,d]/(a^4-bd, b^3-cd, c^2-ad, a^3b^2c-d^3) \cong \mathbb C[t^9,t^{13},t^{16},t^{23}]$. Let $I=(a,b,c)$ and $P=(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: For another example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/851050/121097).