# A formula for Frobenius number of certain numerical semigroups

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

The old formula for the Frobenius number of a numerical semigroup generated by two elements can be stated as follows: assume $\gcd\{a+1,b+1\}=1$, then the Frobenius number of $S= \left<a+1,b+1\right>$ is $ab-1$.

Now let $n\geq 2$ be some fixed integer. Let $A= \{a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n\}$ be a list of positive integers and $x_i = 1+ \sum_{j=0}^{n-2}{a_ia_{i+1}...a_{i+j}}$ and let $S_A  =\left< x_1,\dots, x_n\right>$ be the semigroup generated by the $x_i$s.

For example, when $n=3$, for a triplet $A=\{a,b,c\}$ we have the generators $ab+a+1, bc+b+1,ca+c+1$ for $S_A$. My problem is:

> Problem: suppose $\gcd\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}=1$ and they minimally generate $S_A$. Then show that the Frobenius number of $S_A$ is $(n-1)(a_1a_2...a_n-1)$.

If correct, this is an obvious generalization of the old formula for two generators. I imagine in three variables this can be shown by some brute force, but any comments/proof would be appreciated.

Motivation: from trying to solve [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149713/square-of-primary-ideals/289535#289535). A counter example can be built by starting with a triplet $a,b,c>1$, build $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as above, and throw in $x_4= (abc-1)$. With $\{a,b,c\}= \{2,3,4\}$ we get $R=k[t^9,t^{13},t^{16},t^{23}]$ as in my example. When $\{a,b,c\}= \{2,2,3\}$, we get $R=k[t^7,t^{9},t^{10},t^{11}]$ as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Two questions: 1) In the definition of the $x_i$, how do you interpret $a_{i+j}$ when $i+j>n$? 2) What does it mean to minimally generate $S_A$?

Comment: @EFinat-S: 1) I simply take $i+j \mod n$ 2) If you drop any $x_i$, they no longer generate $S_A$.

Comment: I was thinking of applying the characterization of the Frobenius number due to Selmer, but I have not had time to work on this. See the Lemma in page 2 in
Selmer, Ernst S.
On the linear Diophantine problem of Frobenius.
J. Reine Angew. Math. 293/294 (1977), 1–17. 

This can be freely downloaded from https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002193728